# Objective C - Offloading to separate threads & optimizing speed of app

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, optimization

So once again I have an issue and I'm not quite sure how to go about dealing with it. I have a UICollectionView whose contents are updated as such:

1. User slides up a settings panel (UICollectionView is dimmed out by translucent view overlay).
2. User pushes various buttons to change the object(s) that the UICollectionView displays. Object is updated simultaneously (some settings take longer than others to update).
3. User slides the settings panel down.
4. UICollectionView is updated based off of new object.

The problem is that the program comes to a halt (for a good 3-4 seconds) with every action performed above. I understand that offloading some of these tasks to other threads is somehow involved here. I'm just a bit confused as to which tasks to offload to other threads and how to assure that they have been completed before the next actions occur on the main thread.

So with that, my question - where (and how) would I go about offloading any/all of the above tasks to other threads to keep my app running smoothly? Also, how would I check that the offloaded task has been completed so the main thread can complete its next task? Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Are any of these actions grabbing something off the internet? It doesn't seem like any of the things you mentioned should take 3 or 4 seconds, so you may have other problems.

Comment: @rdelmar - Nothing is being grabbed off of the net. Whenever an option is selected, though, there's a fair bit of calculation involved to decipher which objects meet the user's criteria. Maybe the object shouldn't be updated until the user closes the settings panel?